# Can't access to certain page from my website using Laravel and Authentification

Tags: php, laravel

I hope you are well. I have a site under Laravel using the OVH could web. I connect in FTP in order to update a file (the web.php file, it allows to define the routes of the site). I had put a middleware on some routes but I removed them in ftp. I return to my site but it still asks me to log in. So I tried it locally and this change works fine.

I'm using the Breeze framework.

Here is an example of what I had in route.php :
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'test', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){`

So I removed the 2nd part, which gives:
`Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function(){`

But it still doesn't work. Do you know if there is another place where I could indicate that an authentication is required in order to go to the page please?

Cordially

Comment: do you have a route within this group?

Comment: Yes I do, its like that : `Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function(){
 Route::get('/', [TestController::class, 'test1'])->name('test1');

 Route::get('list_test_2', [TestController::class, 'test2'])->name('test2');

 Route::get('list_test_3', [TestController::class, 'test3'])->name('test3');`